# What is equivalent of moq.As in JustMock?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, moq, justmock

I am stuck to mock Entity Framework 6 asynchronous methods using JustMock. I searched in Google a lot but did not get any sufficient result. At last I got an example at [testing with async queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async) but it is used Moq.

I am try to convert this into JustMock but i can not find anything like `.As<TInterface>()` in JustMock.
Please tell me what is equivalent of moq.As in JustMock ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is no *pure* equivalent option on this framework to `Moq.As<TInterface>`.

But, on Telerik's official [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/scenarios-mock-multiple-interfaces.html), multiple interface mocking is explained using `as` C# protected word.

```
// Arrange
var foo = Mock.Create<IFoo>();
var iDisposable = foo as IDisposable; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Read this documentation and try the solution proposed to do so.